# How to convert summations into matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

In an inner product space with finite dimensions and bases $\{ e_i \}$, we have the gram matrix $G$ where $G_{ij}:= \langle e_i, e_j \rangle$.

Now suppose that we change the bases from $\{ e_i \}$ to $\{ \tilde{e}_i \}$, and the new bases can be represented using $S$ with the old bases. The Gram matrix then changes as well, and this can be seen easily:

$$
\tilde{G}_{ij} = \langle \tilde{e}_i, \tilde{e}_j \rangle = \langle e_kS^k_i, e_lS^l_j \rangle = \langle e_i, e_j \rangle S^k_i S^l_j. 
$$

Keep in mind that Einstein summation is used here. In the text I'm following, this is the same as saying that $\tilde{G} = S'GS$. Seeing the reverse direction is simple enough, but how does one get the forward conclusion? I'm in a math graduate program and the art of building matrices still eludes me. I would like a general approach, if possible.

Comment: For some reason \{ and \} doesn't work. The bases should be a set, not just an element obviously.

Comment: Ohh it only doesn't show in edit mode. In the actual post the curly braces do appear.

Comment: you actually do not need to build these matrices, you can, if you want to, completely get that result by interpreting basis as isomorphisms $ b,\overline{b}:\mathrm{k)^n \xrightarrow{\sim} V $ and so $ S=\overline{b} \circ b^{-1} $. Your $G$ is the unique linear map making $ \langle v,w\rangle$ into $w^t b^{-1}\circ G b\circ v$ and so you get the transformation immediately just from the maps playing in the back. I understand though if this interpretation is a little advanced.

Comment: @Enkidu can you please re-format that, I can't parse the tex since I don't use some of the commands

Comment: I am very sorry, I can try, however, only when I am at home as it not working kinda confuses me and might make it into an hour long drag. Either way, all I wanted to say is that the above can be observed without using matrices at all. However, these points of view might be a little bit advanced, which is ok, it took me 10 years to get to the point I am at.

Comment: @Enkidu I tried to fix it myself, on overleaf. I understand that there is a one-one relationship between a matrix such as $G$ and an inner product. But I do not understand $w^t b^{-1}\circ G b\circ v$. Do you mean $(b \circ w)^T G (b \circ v)$?

Comment: @Enkidu if what I said above is correct, then I see, by simply denoting $S = \overline{b} \circ b$, we then have $(b\circ w)^TG(b \circ v) = (\overline{b} \circ b^{-1} \circ b\circ w)^TG(\overline{b} \circ b^{-1} \circ b \circ v) = (Sw)^TG(Sv)$

Comment: But that is not the question. I have difficulties "compacting" sums in linear algebra into matrix notations, which I sometimes need. I can 'feel' that a summation can be written as some $w^TGv$, but often can't get the right expression by myself.

Comment: @Enkidu I meant $(b\circ w)^TG(b \circ v) = (\overline{b} \circ b^{-1} \circ b\circ w)^TG(\overline{b} \circ b^{-1} \circ b \circ v) = (\overline{b} \circ w)^TS^TGS(\overline{b} \circ v)$, can't edit anymore